# considerations to be taken to choose the best approach for setting up MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Currently we got a Master Slave Setup for our production environemnt .

Coming days we would have more load on our MongoDB as there would be more number of users will be added to our Site (which thus results more load on our Mongodb)

My question is that is it good to have `Master Master` Set up instead of `Master Slave` ?? Other than this i also see that using `replicaset` is a good option for production environment .

Please suggest what are the considerations to be taken to choose the best approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not do a multiple master setup, it does replica sets: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/ slave replication through master->slave is deprecated and if you are running that in production I highly recommend you switch to relpica sets.